# Best practice for Active Directory user management with IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

What is the recommended approach for user management with IdentityServer4 and Active Directory?

I have started with the IdentityServer4 ASP.NET Core interactive quick start and all is working well. However, the sample code uses the `TestUserStore`, `TestUserProfileService` etc., and it seems prudent to replace usage of these.

The 'real-world' alternative seems to be using ASP.NET Core Identity, however this persists user details to the IdentityServer database. Given that IdentityServer isn't the source of truth for this data, this is an odd fit.

Apart from the "test" nature of the quick start classes, these are serving our needs well. Our IdentityServer instance is for internal staff in a small organisation, so the in-memory nature of these stores isn't a problem.

This seems to be a fairly common use-case, so I must be missing something. Can one just delegate all user profile calls to Active Directory? Is there any out of the box code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by implementing and registering an `IProfileService` for Active Directory. It still seems oddly hand-rolled, but seems to do the trick.

Comment: I am working on solution to provide authentication by connecting to on prem AD. Can you please share details about your implementation.

Comment: It was for a work project, so can't really share the code unfortunately. You need to implement `IProfileService`, and it to `IIdentityServerBuilder` with `.AddProfileService<T>()` . In `GetProfileDataAsync()` I retrieve the user by SID (`context.Subject.GetSubjectId()`, create a collection of claims from the user (`given_name`, etc.), then set `context.IssuedClaims`. I then call `context.LogIssuedClaims` for troubleshooting. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Identity Server is an implementation of OAuth 2.0 and OpenIDConnect(Built upon OAuth2.0). The key point of OAuth 2.0 is to pretect resource such as WebApi based on Access Token. So what does OAuth 2.0 provided is Authorization.
2. Identity Server can provide Authenticate service provided by ASP.NET Core Identity, as specified in [This Document](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html#asp-net-identity-support)

In your case, you'd like to delegate the authenticate part to AD, and authorization part to Identity Server. You can refer to [This document](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html#windows-authentication) to enable windows authenticate in your asp.net core application

Comment: That's all understood and not my question. Authentication is already being performed by AD and authorisation by IdentityServer. My question is replacement of the Test* classes. If they're removed from the QuickStart, no identity claims are present in the identity token.

Comment: Specifically, when `AddTestUsers()` is removed, external AD authentication works but no identity claims are present.

As well as adding the in-memory user store, this method adds a test implementation of `IProfileService`. Out of the box, there is a default profile service as well as an ASP.NET Identity profile service. 

I am assuming that I need to provide some manner of AD profile service. My question is whether this really needs to be hand-rolled, or if I'm solving the wrong problem.

Comment: See [ExternalController](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs) in the QuickStart, specifically `AutoProvisionUser()` and `FindByExternalProvider()`.